# Magento Log main.INFO: Broken reference:

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I know this is a common problem and there is a workaround for this error but it didn't helped me.

I uploaded 1column.xml in app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/page_layout with  this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container name="sidebar.additional" label="Sidebar Additional" htmlTag="div">
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="sale.reorder.sidebar" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="wishlist_sidebar" remove="true" />
    <referenceBlock name="custom.sidebar.content" remove="true" />
</container>
</layout>
```

**but this was not the solution** because after that update you can't see the very important blocks like: compare etc

the error LOG says:
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.compare.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.additional**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'sale.reorder.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.additional**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'wishlist_sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.additional**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'custom.sidebar.content' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.additional**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'catalog.product.related.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.main**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.info.upsell.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.main**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'product.brand.img.sidebar' element cannot be added as child to '**sidebar.main**', because **the latter doesn't exist** [] []

So I tried to change my 1column.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<container name="sidebar.additional" label="Sidebar Additional" htmlTag="div">
</container>
<container name="sidebar.main" label="Sidebar Main" htmlTag="div">
</container>
</layout>
```

This looks like all blocks stays where the should and the errors are also gone. Do you think this is the correct solution?

***Now I have also this errors:***

```
main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_before' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_before.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'skip_gallery_after' tries to reorder itself towards 'product.info.media.image', but their parents are different: 'skip_gallery_after.wrapper' and 'product.info.media' respectively. [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'view.addto.compare.additional' tries to reorder itself towards 'view.addto.wishlist', but their parents are different: 'product.info.addto.additional' and 'product.info.addto' respectively. [] []

main.INFO: Broken reference: the 'page.main.title' tries to reorder itself towards 'breadcrumbs', but their parents are different: 'page.top' and 'page.main.title' respectively. [] []
```

So what should I do here?
My Theme developer is not answering so I have to try a fix by myself...